# "Unable to delete the user account" in Users & Groups?

Tags: user-account, macos

On OS 10.9.2, with permissions unlocked, my admin user gets "Unable to delete the user account [username]" when I click the "minus" delete button.

I checked the option to archive the user in the Deleted Users folder, and the error message says, "An error occurred while backing up this user's home folder". Any ideas? Can't see any permissions errors, etc. that are obvious.

Comment: Have you tried "repair volume" as well as repair permission in disk utility?

Comment: Yep, repaired both volume and permissions (only minor errors on either), hard drive has lots of space (3x the size of the profile being deleted).

Comment: Try archiving the user folder manually (create an image or move it, etc.). Then try deleting again